# how to check/un-check all the checkboxs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML code

```
<div class="friends_container">
   <div class="friend">
       <input type="checkbox" />    
      ...
   </div>
<div class="friend">
       <input type="checkbox" />    
      ...
   </div>
<div class="friend">
       <input type="checkbox" />    
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

with select all/ unselect all link

```
<a id="selectall" href="#" >select all</a>
```

I tried to make it work, but I failed.. any help?

JsFiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/R54hs/)

Comment: There are _n_ questions about checking/unchecking checkboxes on SO. Isn't that enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method for this purpose.

```
$(function() {
    var $checkboxes = $('.friends_container>.friend>input:checkbox');
    $('#selectall').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $checkboxes.prop('checked', function() {
            return !this.checked;
        });
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/hh33f/)

Comment: **click** is not a proper event for checkboxes, I think the **change** event is better

Comment: @ABFORCE take a look to HTML in question or my demo. `#selectall` is a anchor element. The requirement was to check/uncheck checkboxes when user clicks on it.

Comment: well, but what happens when i execute `$('#selectall').attr('checked','checked');` ? by this the requirement will not meet

Comment: You won't do this for `a#selectall` I think.

Answer (score 2):

with changing  your link to checkbox, it will be easy

try this

```
<input id="selectall" type="checkbox"  />select all
```

**js**

```
 $('#selectall').click(function(){
    $('.friend').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked',this.checked);
})
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJg8N/1/)

---

with `a` link

```
$('#selectall').click(function(){
    $('.friend').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
})
```

create one more link to unselect the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

To check -

`$("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);`

To uncheck -

`$("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);`

Doing it using an anchor -

```
$("#selectall").click(function(){
   $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
});
```

And also if you have some anchor for deselecting -

`<a id="deselectall" href="#" >deselect all</a>`

you can add deselect all listener to it -

```
$("#deselectall").click(function(){
   $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//checkall
$('#selectall').on('click', function (e) {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
    e.preventDefault();
});
//uncheck all
$('#unselectall').on('click', function (e) {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selectall').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery `version 1.6 +` use `prop`

```
$("#input[type='checked']").prop('checked',true);
```

jquery `version 1.6 -` use `attr`

```
$("#input[type='checked']").attr('checked','checked');
```

or

```
$("#input[type='checked']").attr('checked',true);
```

Comment: `true` is not a valid value for checked property

Comment: That said, when using `prop` to set checked/selected you should use a boolean instead of a string.

Comment: @ABFORCE modified ans....